# How to make two-way binding in mat-select work

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have following code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="valueFromDB.name">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.name"
      >{{option.name}}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

valueFromDB = new Option('Option');
```

And I suppose then on loading I got option2 selected. But instead I have empty selection. What am I doing wrong?
[Working sample is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grupfc-utklqo?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts).

Comment: More likely a typo error. You don't have any options with name: "Option". Based on your data, you should set: `valueFromDB = new Option('Option2')`;

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that it doesn't work because the option 'Option' is not in the array options. Make sure that exactly such a string 'Option' is present in the array. For example, if you have this array

```
 options = [
    new Option('Option1'),
    new Option('Option2'),
    new Option('Option3'),
  ];
```

here you must have not 'Option' but 'Option1' or another from the array `valueFromDB = new Option('Option1');`